# 401 Unauthorized error with WebDeploy using non-administrator user and IIS user on Windows Server 2016

Tags: asp.net, iis, webdeploy

I am getting 401 error when trying to deploy remotely. 
Event log from server -

```
The following information was included with the event: 

IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_NOT_ALLOWED


Only Windows Administrators are allowed to connect using a server connection. Other users should use the 'Connect To Site or Application' task to be able to connect.

Process:WMSvc
User=deployer
```

I am using following script to deploy

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Jenkins\workspace\Myproject.zip -   dest:auto,wmsvc=[server_ip],usernverame=iis_deployer,password=iis_deployer,authType=basic -setparam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='Default Web Site\myproject\master' -allowUntrusted
```

It works fine if I use the admin user. But it fails for non-admin and IIS users.

I have tried to set the permission and delegated rules by following this article-
https://blogs.iis.net/krolson/using-iis-manager-accounts-for-web-deployment-tool-msdeploy-delegation

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this error for hours and I found the solution. In the MsDeploy.exe command line you must specify the site name in the "wmsvc" parameter. For instance:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='d:\temp\xxx.zip' -dest:auto,wmsvc="https://192.168.XXX.XXX:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Test",userName='usr',password='pwd',includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension  -AllowUntrusted -retryAttempts=2 -setParam:'IIS Web Application Name'='Test'
```